# How can I access my virtually hosted website from any phone or pc?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, vhosts, ubuntu-server

I have a linux server running on my local environemnt. I have setup two website and virtually hosted them and the hosting is name based.

My Host machine configuaration is:

All the directory has proper permission.

`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName nextcloud.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud.local

```
<Directory /var/www/nextcloud.local>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_access.log combined
```

`

I have also edited /etc/hosts
192.168.0.105 nextcloud.local

On my laptop that running windows I have edited the file C:/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts and put
this line 192.168.0.105 nextcloud.local

I have also edited the trusted domain of nextcloud.

And browsing nextcloud.local on windows machine works fine.

Now how can I access those website from any devices such as phone or table of the same network by just browsng nextcloud.local.

Comment: _"Now how can I access those website from any devices such as phone or table of the same network by just browsng nextcloud.local."_ - what's your LAN's DNS infrastructure? Does your WLAN share the same broadcast domain as your wired LAN?

Comment: I'd create a private tunnel for accessing these services outside a local network for definite security reasons if it's granting administrative access.